# EdgeJS makes an Async call without accompanying Await

Tags: node.js, async-await, edgejs

I am looking into solutions to call some C# code from within my NodeJS application. I came across EdgeJS, which seems to make this possible. However, I came across part of their code that is confusing to me, because I see an `async` keyword without an accompanying `await`. And while I'm more familiar with JS than C#, my understanding is that in BOTH you need to include an `await` with any `async`. This is the code in question, where some multi-line C# code is defined within backticks:

```
var edge = require('edge');
 
var helloWorld = edge.func(`
    async (input) => { 
        return ".NET Welcomes " + input.ToString(); 
    }
`);
 
helloWorld('JavaScript', function (error, result) {
    if (error) throw error;
    console.log(result);
});
```

Can someone explain how this is working, considering `await` doesn't appear anywhere?

Comment: You know you can just run from the CMD .exe file(c#)

Comment: I'm not sure what you're referring to. How does that address the question about `async/await`?